# A student must answer five out of $10$ questions on a test, including at least two of the first five questions.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

A student must answer five out of $10$ questions on a test, including at least two
of the first five questions. How many subsets of five questions can be answered?

$$\binom52\binom53+\binom53\binom52+\binom54\binom51+\binom55$$

if im correct , is there any other way to think about this problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you’ve done is correct. You could also have calculated

$$\binom{10}5-\binom51\binom54+\binom55\;,$$

i.e., the total number of ways to choose $5$ questions minus the number of ways that include $1$ or $0$ questions from the first $5$.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct.

You need to choose at least 2 from first 5. So you have 2 from first 5, 3 from the other group; 3 from first 5, 2 from the other group; 4 from first 5, 1 from the other group; all 5 from the first group of 5